# In Javascript, how do I print out the Date object's date and time without the timezone?

Tags: javascript, string, date

In Javascript, how do I print out a date with the date and time only?  If I do this,

```
(new Date(params['mydate'])).toString();
```

I get

```
Fri Jan 08 2021 10:57:20 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

but if I try "toDateString",

```
(new Date(params['mydate'])).toDateString();
```

I don't get the time at all ...

```
Fri Jan 08 2021
```

Any way to include the time without the timezone?

Comment: `new Date().toString().slice(0,24)` gives something like "Mon Jan 18 2021 08:29:22".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) and [`.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

```js
let d = new Date();
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString() + " " + d.toLocaleTimeString());
```